# Clarification on REST APIs around user management in an account

Tags: docusignapi

I recently created a docusign developer account and integrator key and was playing with docusign REST APIs and had some questions

1. I can retrieve full list of users under my account by using following REST call.
   `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<accountid>/users?additional_info=true`

   However if I try and retrieve a specific user (other than the one I am passing in my X-Docusign-authentication) header i get http 400 error with message that the "Invalid UserId. UserId specified in request uri does not match authenticated user"

   `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<accountid>/users/0d51a699-b17a-48b7-95b6-1e9e9806deb6`

   In both cases i am sending the following header.

   `X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{0}</Username><Password>{1}</Password><IntegratorKey>{2}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>`

   I am surprised that while I can read all users fine, I cannot just read one specific user. Surely it doesn't seem like this is security thing since I can read the user via one API but not the other using the same auth token.

   What am i missing?

   I guess I can go the route of SOBO (Send on behalf of functionality), but I wanted to confirm if above behavior is expected.

***Update#1***

: I went the SOBO [approach](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/OAuth2/Acting%20As%20Other%20Account%20Users.htm) and now i get a different error (USER_NOT_ACCOUNT_ADMIN) as shown below

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountid}/users/0fe29a55-5564-42a9-b09d-cbe699db13dd HTTP/1.1
Authorization: bearer {token for authenticating user}
X-DocuSign-Act-As-User: {operating user's email}
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 100
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 17 Oct 2013 21:18:32 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains

{
  "errorCode": "USER_NOT_ACCOUNT_ADMIN",
  "message": "User is not an account administrator."
}
```

I also tried the second SOBO approach of getting a oauth token for the operating user but got back http 400 error with below message

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "An OAuth2 error occurred."
}
```

So while i can get an oauth token for the autheitcating user, i am not able obtain oauth token for the operating user or act on their behalf.

I have made sure that authenticating user is "Account Administrator" and has both "apiAccountWideAccess" and "•allowSendOnBehalfOf" set to true. The only thing set to "false" is "canSendAPIRequests". My account id in sandbox environment is "601565a7-e9c7-463b-9d7c-622aed905ea8" Any ideas?

***Update#2***

Instead of generating oauth tokens on behalf of both authenticating user and operating user, i tried passing below header and i can finally get another user's profile and update another user's profile.

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><SendOnBehalfOf>{operating userid}</SendOnBehalfOf><Username>{authenticating userid}</Username><Password>{authenticating user's password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{developer's integrator key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

Great! 
So here is status of what works and what doesn't.

***Works with no SOBO header anywhere***

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users?additional_info=true // Read all users  
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users?email=someshchandraatwork@gmail.com&additional_info=true // Read single user by email
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users // Add users
DELETE /restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users // Close users
```

****Works with SOBO in X-DocuSign-Authentication header***

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users/74a021e1-3090-4843-b9ab-cceb7cd119f4/profile // Update user's profile
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users/74a021e1-3090-4843-b9ab-cceb7cd119f4/profile // Read user's profile
```

Still doesn't work with or without SOBO**

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users/74a021e1-3090-4843-b9ab-cceb7cd119f4/settings 
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users/74a021e1-3090-4843-b9ab-cceb7cd119f4
```

In both not working cases i get following error

- Without SOBO i get error that userid doesn't match autheitcating user.
- With SOBO i get error than user is not an account admin

I would very much appreciate any help in resolving the not working cases. I can provide more detaisl as needed.

1. Secondly I want to implement a scenario where I can deactivate a user in an account so they can no longer log into docusign. And subsequently I would like to enable that user back again with same permission that they had before they were disabled.

   I see that user has a "userStatus" field and was wondering if I can use that to de-activate the user and then re-activate if needed. If this is supported then what value would correspond to deactivating the user?

   The other thing I note is that on DELETE a user, the user is only soft-deleted since I can still query the user with the status "CLOSED". That would solve my "deactivate" problem. However I was not sure if there is a way to reactivate them back again after the user has been "closed"?

Comment: Any ideas why HTTP GET request on "/restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users/74a021e1-3090-4843-b9ab-cceb7cd119f4/profile" succeeds but GET on "/restapi/v2/accounts/357938/users/74a021e1-3090-4843-b9ab-cceb7cd119f4" **fails** despite using SOBO in the header.I have tried creating a new integrator key,used a different admin user, stared at permissions and documentations for many hours ,but can't figure out why the second request fails and first one succeeds. The only explanation i can offer is that perhaps some account settings is missing or there is a bug in docusign end.Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be an account administration issue.  I'm not sure why but I looked at your account settings from DocuSign's side and I saw the "Send on Behalf of" was not checked on your account- which is weird since it seems you have access to the setting in your Console -> Preferences settings.

But in either case I'm wondering if the setting I just enabled on your account has solved your issue, as it might have.

I'm also not sure about the user info portion of your question, let me see if I can come up with anything for that and I'll edit my answer once I do.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Ergin.I tried again and i get the same error. 1.) GET on https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountid}/users/0fe29a55-5564-42a9-b09d-cbe699db13dd along with "X-DocuSign-Authentication" header gives back "..authenticated user is not the same as userid in uri..". 2) SOBO via oauth token of authenticating user and "X-DocuSign-Act-As-User:" header fails withe same error message "USER_NOT_ACCOUNT_ADMIN" 3) Trygint to get oauth token for "operating user" fails with the message "An OAuth2 error occurred".I am curious which one of the above was expected to pass?

Comment: More generally i want to understand if for creating/updating/deleting users in an account on behalf of an  account admin, do we need SOBO or will having account admin's username/password and using an integrator key that we(developer) create suffice?

Comment: Anyone who is an account admin should be able to modify/add/delete users in an account.  I'm not sure if your SOBO steps are correct though, can you confirm that you are following [THESE STEPS](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo) exactly?  If so, at which step do you run into issues or get an error?

Comment: I added more details in my answer below. Also to clarify that for us (developer) to use an admin's credentials to add/delete/modify other users in the account, is it **mandatory** to follow SOBO process? Can we not just use X-DocuSign-Authentication header : <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{admins't username}</Username><Password>{admins's password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{developer's integrator key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>

Comment: Test it out, but I believe you should be able to just use admin's info in the header

Comment: yes. so far i have had success in most cases passing just XDocusign header.

Comment: Btw, any recommendation on the deactivate/reactivate scenario? Currently i am choosing to "DELETE" the user during "deactivation" and for "reactivation" creating a new user with the same email and default set of permissions. This solution is not ideal , but this is only way i have found which completely blocks a user from signing into docusign during deactivation which is important for us. I notice that the UI has "Send Activation" link which can convert the user form "CLOSED" to "Active" again. Can i achieve the same via APIs?

Answer (score 1):

In reply to Erign's post above.

*Anyone who is an account admin should be able to modify/add/delete users in an account. I'm not sure if your SOBO steps are correct though, can you confirm that you are following THESE STEPS exactly? If so, at which step do you run into issues or get an error?–  Ergin5 mins ago*

Yes i am following those steps. I am able to generate oauth token for the autheitcating user , but get an error when doing the same for the operating user. Below are my request and responses.

***1. REQUEST FOR AUTH TOKEN FOR AUTHENTICATING USER***

```
POST /restapi/v2/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 139
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=password&client_id={integratorykey}&username={authenticating user's email}&password={authenticating user's password}&scope=api
```

***RESPONSE***

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 100
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 17 Oct 2013 22:57:26 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains

{
  "access_token": "{authenticating user's token}",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "scope": "api"
}
```

***2. REQUEST FOR AUTH TOKEN FOR OPERATING USER***

```
POST /restapi/v2/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: bearer {authenticating user's token}
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 137
Expect: 100-continue

grant_type=password&client_id={integratorykey}&username={operating user's id}&password={empty}&scope=api
```

***RESPONSE***

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 87
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 17 Oct 2013 22:57:29 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains

{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "An OAuth2 error occurred."
}
```

Comment: Ok I think I know what's going on with your OAuth2 error.  There's a limit of 10 tokens per account, and I believe you get that error when you reach the limit.  Try deleting at least one token by going to Preferences -> Connected Apps then try requesting a new again and it should work...

Comment: I checked and i only have one connected application in my account. I remember seeing this error due to the 10 apps limit but i can confirm that in this case it is definitely not the cause of the error. Perhaps there are some other limits that i may be hitting? Any other ideas?

Comment: I created a new demo account and same issue. Perhaps this is a limitation of demo accounts in general? I also tried using Docusign API-Explorer to see example request/response for SOBO tokens but i see that failing as well. The API-Explorer seems to be always passing "blah" as the username for operating user instead of the user i want it to use.