# Unable to update password of a user using docusign rest api

Tags: docusignapi

As per the documentation we can update the password of an user

https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Users/Users/update/

We are sending a put request and we also get a 200 response but the password doesnt get updated. We have tried updating other fields and they update successfully. Wondering if there is a workaround.

Endpoint we are using - /restapi/v2/accounts/1234565/users/1753ad37-2f9a-421e-8b10-1b4b42345ffa. Note: Account ID and User Id in the URL are just examples

```
{
  "password" : "step➛Pre Processing➛new_password"
}
```

Comment: Please review answer and let us know what yielded a result from debugging the process.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple reasons this could happen:

1. Your Account is using Single Sign On (SSO) via Okta, MS AD, etc
2. Your Authentication permissions are not correct to change the password aka SOBO (Send on behalf of ) and the user your are tying to change is a View only user (they can't send, you can't do things as them) This Stack Overflow question covers SOBO as well as the one below covers Classic Authentication/SOBO
   [Clarification on REST APIs around user management in an account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416784/clarification-on-rest-apis-around-user-management-in-an-account)
   [How should the header X-DocuSign-Authentication be used for REST and SOAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028119/how-should-the-header-x-docusign-authentication-be-used-for-rest-and-soap)
3. Your Account (Support and/or Account Rep will need to confirm) is configured in a way that prohibits user password changes and only allows resets
4. And you "Can't" update the password using SOBO - See the SOBO feature discussed here https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html

You can you capture exact JSON/SOAP request posted by your API calls by following steps explained at this DocuSign support article https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your response, the 1st point is out of question as we do not have SSO or AD integration, we are checking the other two and will let you know.. even though we are able to update other fields of a user with the same endpoint and token.. it is just not working for password

Comment: @moiz134 please check #4 as well, it is called out that with SOBO updatepassword will NOT work.